# What is the dwMinorVersion for Windows Server 2008R2 SP1?

Tags: c++, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a code wherein I check whether the OS is Windows 2008R2 or not and do stuff accordingly. The [following link states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx) that for Windows2008R2, the `dwMajorVersion` should be `6` and `dwMinorVersion` would be `1`. In my code I check for these 2 values but I have found by logging those values on Windows 2008R2 SP1 OS that the `dwMinorVersion` is `0`, not `1` like the link states.

Does the fact that it is 2008R2 SP1 change the minor version? Also if indeed this is supposed to be `0`, then how would I differentiate between 2008R2 and 2008?

EDIT: Added the code snippet

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
GetVersionEx((LPOSVERSIONINFO )&osvi);

if(osvi.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1)
  // do something since this is Windows Server 2008R2 OS.
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: My limited understanding of that link seems to suggest that having a service pack installed would not change those values, and that the relevant service pack information would be in `wServicePackMajor` and `wServicePackMinor`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre added the code snippet.

Comment: @Tas True the service pack information would be in wServicePackMajor but I am ok with any ServicePack version. I just want to detect whether it is a Server 2008R2 OS or not. Based on that link, I had assumed that Major=6 and Minor=1 would mean either Windows7 and Windows2008R2 OS, but when I log those values it is giving me 0 for Minor version.

Comment: Probably your program doesn't have the necessary information in the manifest to say that it is compatible with Windows 7, so Windows is pretending to be Windows Vista.  (Or the server equivalent.)  But see also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140128-00/?p=1943/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/01/14/common-problems-with-checking-os-versions-in-code/

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for the comment Harry. I am new to this so not  sure I fully understand and apologies if this is a silly question but do I have to do something from my end to update the manifest?

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) but I see that actually this only started happening with Windows 8 so it can't explain your observations.  My mistake.  It could still be the PCA as per Raymond Chen's blog, try checking the registry key as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx).  And consider whether you really need to check the OS version - legitimate reasons for doing this are few and far between.

Comment: Need to know the OS because I have a hotfix which specifically needs to be installed if the OS is either Windows7 or Windows Server 2008R2.